# RAID status monitoring HPE Smart Array E208i-p SR Gen10

Tags: linux, raid, adaptec

It shouldn't be this hard, but I can't figure out how to monitor the RAID status with the HPE Smart Array E208i-p SR Gen10, in a HP ProLiant DL360 Gen10 in Linux.

- I can't find a file in `/proc` or `/sys`.
- `arcconf` says: `Controllers found: 0`.
- `ssacli controller all show` says: `Error: No controllers detected.`
- Same for [HP SSA CLI](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_66219ab8d27646d99c028ff389): `Error: No controllers detected.`

Edit: it was a bit confusing because this server has two RAID controllers, but neither work so far, so the question is the same.

This is the `lspci -v` output of the E208i-p:

```
  11:00.0 Serial Attached SCSI controller: Adaptec Smart Storage PQI 12G SAS/PCIe 3 (rev 01)
  Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array E208i-p SR Gen10
  Physical Slot: 1
  Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26, NUMA node 0
  Memory at e2800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
  I/O ports at 4000 [size=256]
  Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
  Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=64 Masked-
  Capabilities: [c0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
  Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
  Capabilities: [300] #19
  Kernel driver in use: smartpqi
  Kernel modules: smartpqi
```

This of the P408i-a:

```
    b1:00.0 Serial Attached SCSI controller: Adaptec Smart Storage PQI 12G SAS/PCIe 3 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array P408i-a SR Gen10
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 32, NUMA node 0
    Memory at f3800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    I/O ports at c000 [size=256]
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=64 Masked-
    Capabilities: [c0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [300] #19
    Kernel driver in use: smartpqi
    Kernel modules: smartpqi
```

Linux version:

```
cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
```

Edit: on a slightly order server, with 'Hewlett-Packard Company Smart Array Gen9 Controllers (rev 01) / Hewlett-Packard Company P440', the `hpssacli` tool does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with a P408i-a and an older version of ssacli (ssacli-2.60-19.0). I was able to resolve it by using a newer version of ssacli (ssacli-4.17-6.0).

Comment: Where did you download it? I can only find 2.6x versions.

Comment: OK, I think I found it. [this link](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?swItemId=MTX_9697c6899a664d02b9c3436674) will probably go bad, but I found it by searching for 'ssa cli' [on the main support page](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/home). The root of the problem is that Google is filled with links to old versions. It works BTW, it finds the controller.

Answer (score 0):

For the Red Hat users out there: Install the HP repo (keyfiles are available on the HP repo page); then you can use your package manager to install:

```
[hpsum]
name=HPE Smart Update Manager
baseurl=http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/repo/hpsum/rhel/7Server/x86_64/current/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/GPG-KEY-hpsum

[HP-mcp]
name=HP Management Component Pack for ProLiant
baseurl=http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/mcp/centos/7/x86_64/current/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/GPG-KEY-mcp

[HP-spp]
name=HP Service Pack for ProLiant
baseurl=http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/spp/RHEL/7/x86_64/current/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/GPG-KEY-ssp
```